# Wordpress PHP notices showing only in Safari/Firefox

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am getting php notices on the front-end of seemingly random products since our client updated to woo-commerce 3.0.

http://teresezache.com/product/weston-wear-4/

http://teresezache.com/product/joules-3/

I've turned of debugging and everything looks fine Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look to the PHP-Error Logs and paste it here if possible.

If your server doesnt support PHP, running a CMS based on it isnt going to work ^^

Also you could just read, that the page tells you :

> WC_Product::get_gallery_attachment_ids is deprecated since version 3.0! Use WC_Product::get_gallery_image_ids instead. in /home/tereseza/public_html/teresezache/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3829

It seems like not all files you are using are compatible with the new version.